# Start ubuntu13.04 and then it turns to black screen

Tags: boot, grub2, intel-graphics, 13.04

I do need help. I just updated 12.10 to 13.04 but the problem occured. 
Every time I start my laptop it turns to a black screen. After the grub and the purple screen. And I also hear the voice from the password interface. This means the system has started sucessfully but the screen is black. I can see nothing.
And if I go into recovery mode and then choose Resume option, the black screen goes.
Why? I have googled a lot and tried a lot but none works. By the way, the graphic ui is a little bit slower than 12.10.
My laptop is acer aspire s3, with a Intel GMA HD 4000 graphics. 
 
Hope somebody could help me.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it?

Comment: I have read it and it seems no help for me. @Lucio

Comment: If none of those options work then you need to file a bug please!

Comment: OK. I will do that. There is reason for me to believe that the graphics drivers doesn't work of my Intel card. @JorgeCastro